# Writing to a TMemoryStream and losing unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm getting a weird behavior when copying a TMemoryStream (containing unicode string) to another TMemoryStream, using Delphi XE2:

I have two instances of a TMemoryStream. The first instance contains unicode text (SourceMS). I write some arbitrary data to the second MemoryStream (DestMS) and then copy the contents of the first stream to the second stream, like that:

```
var
  SomeInt: Integer;
  SomeByte: Byte;
  SourceMS, DestMS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ...
  DestMS.Write(SomeInt, SizeOf(SomeInt));
  DestMS.Write(SomeByte, SizeOf(SomeByte));
  SourceMS.SaveToFile('c:\SourceMS.txt');  // SourceMS.txt contains the unicode chars
  DestMS.CopyFrom(SourceMS, 0);          // copy the whole content of SourceMS to DestMS   
  DestMS.SaveToFile('c:\DestMS.txt');  // DestMS.txt DOEST NOT contain unicode chars              
end;
```

How can I copy the contents of the first stream to the second stream without losing unicode (having an implicit conversion)?
When I say "losing unicode", I mean: The unicode string is indeed copied to the second stream, but the unicode is lost. I get ANSI chars only.

Comment: Are your `MS1` and `MS2` variables correctly sequenced in your example?

Comment: when you say `..I write some arbitrary data to the second MemoryStream and then copy the contents of the first stream to the second stream` Are you aware which maybe you are replacing the [`BOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the second stream?

Comment: @James: This is just a piece of code. MS2 is already filled with data when the CopyFrom method is called.

Comment: @RRUZ: Yes, that crossed my mind. But I don't see how writing a BOM to the second stream would solve that issue. I've never written BOM to any stream before and copy from/to streams never gave me that behavior.

Comment: @James: I've changed the code to be more clear

Comment: @Alexandre, there's a bug somewhere in **your** code; Unfortunately that bug is **not in the 5 lines of code you posted**. You're suggesting that this problem is somewhat related to `TMemoryStream`, but that's highly unlikely: it's such a basic `RTL` class, practically used in every single Delphi program out there. If it had a bug, we'd know about it. You should post a *Short But Complete Example*, something we can easily copy-paste into the `IDE` and prove the error. I do not believe you'll succeed: most likely you'll find your own bug while trying.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `DestMS` is just some arbitrary bytes and that `SourceMS` is where your Unicode content resides.  If you append `source` to `dest`, then the `BOM` from `source` will not be at the beginning of the memory stream.  When you open the saved text file in Windows, it won't see the `BOM` because it isn't at the beginning of the file, so it won't know that other characters later in the file should be treated as Unicode.

It appears that you are trying to insert some content at the front of the Unicode content.

If this is true, then you could place the Unicode content in a Unicode compliant control, add the characters to the beginning and then capture the content from the control.  This would keep the `BOM` at the beginning of the byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what could happen, if we were to judge this based exclusively on the 5 lines of code that were posted. `TMemoryStream` does not alter the the bytes in any way, we have to assume the raw bytes were successfully copied from one `.txt` file to the other. Both files should contain the exact same bytes, yet when viewing the files with a Text Viewer application, those same bytes are not interpreted the same way.

I can only imagine one such case:

- One of the files has a BOM, most likely UTF8.
- The other file has no BOM, so it's interpreted as ANSI.

It doesn't even matter which file has a BOM: going through such a process changes the way bytes are interpreted. According to Wikipedia, the vast majority of code pages are a super-set of ASCII, meaning that all bytes that can be written using 7bit are interpreted the exact same way with both UTF8 and ANSI. The "Unicode" characters that the OP complains about are certainly in the "extend" ANSI (8bit) or, when using UTF8, they're composed using 2 or more bytes. This gives the failure modes:

- If the original is a ANSI file that contains extended characters (non-ASCII), if those were interpreted as UTF8, the result would probably look a bit like garbage: Two (or more) characters of the original file would seem to be replaced by some weird character.
- If the original was UTF8, then all international characters would be represented using a minimum of two bytes: When interpreted as ANSI those two bytes would be represented as two distinct characters, according to the code page of the PC.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFrom` does indeed copy the whole source stream into the target stream, but it starts at the current position of the target. The arbitrary data written before still exists!

You should set `MS1.Position := 0` before you call `CopyFrom`.

Comment: Perhaps `MS1` should be cleared before doing the `CopyFrom`, so that if `MS2` is smaller than `MS1`, extra bytes won't be left at the end of the stream after the copy.

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for your answer. In fact, if pass 0 as the second parameter in CopyFrom call (parameter Count), the Source.Position is set to zero, and the whole stream is copied (Check method TStream.CopyFrom source in System.Classes.pas)

Comment: @Alexandre, yes, that is what I wrote. But the source stream is appended to the target stream - it doesn't replace the content before the current position.

Comment: @Uwe, yes but thats my intention. I want the unicode string (from the second stream) to be appended to the first stream, without loosing unicode.

Comment: If it is just appending to the target stream, then the BOM won't be at the beginning of the file unless the target stream already has a BOM at its start.  If so, then you will have a BOM at the beginning and then again in the middle of the target stream because it copied the one from the source...  Wouldn't it be better to place both sets of text in a Unicode memo field and then recreate a new stream from it so that the BOMs will be properly resolved/combined?

Comment: Hi James: In fact the SaveToFile method call is just a debug helper. I could read the Stream content as a string also, and wouldn't get the Unicode chars as well. I don't have BOM in the SourceMS either but the Unicode is there...

Comment: After the code `SourceMS.SaveToFile('c:\SourceMS.txt')` executes, have you viewed the TXT file in a Hex Editor to see if it contains a `BOM`?  Or is Windows just detecting that there are some Unicode characters in the TXT file when you open it and properly displaying them?

Comment: Hi James, using an hex editor there is no BOM in TXT files. Notepad++ for instance identify it as Unicode without BOM.

Comment: @Alexandre - Even if there's no BOM, by imposing arbitrary data in the beginning of the file, you're breaking the *unicode*ness of the string. Follow James' advice and view the file with an Hex Editor, you'll see how it's structure is broken.

Comment: you may try to put empty unicode string into MS2 before putting acutal data into it. If it was about BOM, then it could help. But i think it is not about BOM at all. Memory Stream is raw binary data type, not text in any way. So use Hex Viewer to really see raw data. (Most basic viewers wit hHex mode can be found in Unreal Commander, Total Commander or as standalone Universal Viewer).